# friend template function of template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following simplified code:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    template <class U>
    static U foo(T* p)
    {
        p;
        return U();
    }
};

class B
{
    /*template <class T>
    template <class U>
    friend U A<T>::foo<U>(T*);*/
    friend B A<B>::foo<B>(B*);
    B()
    {}
public:
};
...
A<B>::foo<B>(nullptr);
```

And it works quite well. But the things that I've not managed to do are commented:

```
/*template <class T>
template <class U>
friend U A<T>::foo<U>(T*);*/
```

I don't know what the syntax I should use to make it works. So I need to generalize my friend declaration to all possible types. I've tried quite a few variants of syntax but had no success. Could some one point me out what should I write instead of my commented code to make it works?
Thanks!

Comment: `template <class T, class U>`?

Comment: I tried several variants with different compilers, nothing seems to work (and the produced error messages are not helpful).

Comment: I have tried your code on linux with clang 2.8 and g++ 4.5.2 and both were happy with your code...

Comment: This will also work: template <class T> friend class A; But I guess this is not what you want.

Comment: g++ 4.3.4 is not happy with the code: http://ideone.com/oC8OU, http://ideone.com/EEUrI

Comment: Perhaps it needs a `typename` declaration before?

Comment: ... and so does g++ 4.5.1: http://ideone.com/vp5RN, http://ideone.com/v0Vlw

Comment: @Vlad Sorry for confusing the issue, I did not read the original question well enough. It actually says that the posted code is fine. Only the commented out part fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
template <class T>
template <class U>
friend U A<T>::foo(T*);
```

The following works on IdeOne.com

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
  template <class U>
  static U foo(T* p)
  {
    p;
    return U();
  }
};

class B
{
  template <class T>
  template <class U>
  friend U A<T>::foo(T*);

  B() {}

public:
  void hello() const
  {
    std::cout << "I'm a B!" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
  A<B>::foo<B>(NULL).hello();
}
```

Comment: Indeed: http://ideone.com/fNVaK. Still wondering why the syntax for templates is so obscure and why is there a difference between `template <class T> template <class U>` and `template <class T, class U>`.

Comment: Well, thanks! But it still doesn't compile on MSVC2011. So the question now is: whether it is a MSVC bug or it is a gcc "extension".

Comment: Seems like an MSVS bug since it compiles successfully on comeau

Comment: @Vlad I'm no language designer, so I can't say why the syntax is so "obscure;"  I'm sure there are issues that you and I are unaware of.  As for the difference between `template <class T> template <class U> ...` and `template <class T, class U> ...`, I'm pretty sure in the first case there are two templates (one for the class and one for the method), while in the second case there is a single template with two parameters.

Comment: @aldo: as far as I understand, the case of `template <class T, class U>` it's kind of partial template specialization.

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with the othe commenters, friends and templates simply don't mix, at least not in any consistent way with across a range of compilers.  The standard probably states exactly what *should* work, though that will likely not help you.  Sad but true.

Friend is often not a good idea anyhow, it might be better to consider how to write the code without friendship, or use the "poor man's friend" of a public method with a comment indicating it is not for general use.